# How to color an underline on android studio?

Tags: android-studio, colors, fonts, styles, underline

I put on string catagory this code:

```
<string name="MyunderLine"> <u> <font> the_text </font> </u></string>
```

How can I change from here the underline color?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color of the string like this.

```
 <string name="MyunderLine"> <u> <font color="#FF0000"> the_text </font> </u> </string>
```

As far as I know you can't change the color of just the underline using only a string resource.

Comment: Oh, so do you know another way?

Comment: I don't know the context of the string or if you are using Compose or XML.

Comment: I could try to help if you show me the layout code related to this string.